# java.lang.StackOverflowError on implementing Runnable in a JPanel - Java Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, exception, stack-overflow

I have a `JPanel` which implements `Runnable` interface and `overrides` `run()` method. In the constructor of my `JPanel` i initialize a `private` class(`JPanel`) instance of `Thread` which takes as argument a `new MyPanel`.
On this very line i get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

**The errors that comes after**:

```
    at java.awt.Component.setForeground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setForeground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColors(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

**And then**:

```
    at MyPanel.<init>(MyPanel.java:39)
    at MyPanel.<init>(MyPanel.java:45)
```

Line 39 is my `JPanel` constructor and line 45 is the initialization code of the class `Thread` which is `this.generateBallsThread = new Thread(new MyPanel());`

Only relevant to the question code has been putted here.

**MyPanel.java**:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener,Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE; 
    private static final Color NPC_BALLS_COLOR = Color.RED;

    // The player is an oval
    private int playerRadius = 25;
    private int playerX;
    private int playerY;

    // True - first player position, false - otherwise
    private boolean playerPosition = true;

    // Array of all the balls threads
    private ArrayList<BallThread> balls = new ArrayList<BallThread>();

    private Thread generateBallsThread;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        this.setBackground(MyPanel.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);

        this.generateBallsThread = new Thread(new MyPanel()); // StackOverflowError
        generateBallsThread.start();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty confused. This is the way you use the `Runnable` interface so what `java` wants from me?

Comment: You recursivly call constructor of `MyPanel` because of you get `StackOverflowError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `new MyPanel()` with `this`. This will stop the infinitely recursive call that is causing the stack overflow

Comment: That did the job but now i have an `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException` :). But that for another question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

your code is going in infinite loop because of the line
this.generateBallsThread = new Thread(new MyPanel()); , because you are creating the object of class MyPanel in it's constructor, which will again call the same constructor.

Comment: Yeah i wrote that on the post :). Though why all the down votes? Some peaople here have no patience for other problems |:

Answer (score 1):

**Why are you getting an SO exception?** The constructor for the `MyPanel` class creates another `MyPanel`.  This causes the class to continue to be created until the stack bound is exceeded, causing a stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.